# payload from http inbound store and retrieved at 3rd subsequent call in http outbound gateway

Tags: spring-integration

Context : I have inbound gateway which receives http request over json, which then goes to internal gateway, filtered and transformed , and sent to chain of http outbound gateway calls ( 4 calls ) and after 4 calls are complete, response is sent back to inbound gateway to send a response to client.

External System ( client ) calls >  http Inbound gateway --> IFlow ( internal gateway @messaging gateway ) --> filters- transforms - > http outbound gateway --> External system ( api to retrieve data ).

between transform and http outbound gateway - there are 4 http calls over rest i.e. i call 4 external endpoints to get right data and send back to Client.

inbound gateway transforms json to model object at IFlow.  lets say model object is CallModel.
At this point, i want to store this model object because later, i transforms the headers and payload for specific endpoints and if any extra header is there in request, external system throw error ( 409 and etc), therefore i cannot keep values in headers for calling http outbound gateway.

Is it possible to store CallModel or values from it, and not to propogate them for 3 successive http outbound gateway calls , and then at 4th call, i get CallModel and use values from it for 4th calls.

I thought about using a cache or creating a class to store, but perhaps there is a cleaner way.

Comment: actually, title should be : payload from http inbound gateway store and retrieved at 3rd subsequent call in http outbound gateway.  ( instead of payload, a value would also do ) as ideally i want that value to be propogated but not used when i call http outbound calls.

Comment: Please, edit your question respectively: don't add comments - misleading. Thanks

Comment: Custom headers will not be mapped on outbound HTTP requests (unless you have configured the header mapper to do so). [Tests here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-http/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/http/support/DefaultHttpHeaderMapperFromMessageOutboundTests.java#L557).

Comment: Thanks,  then how do i put a string value in the header at first request, and then at 4th request get it back from message.getHeaders() ?

Comment: so, i can add them via custom mapper, then i want to exclude them from propagation across rest calls, and then at 4th call, i want to retrieve the value. Perhaps, this is not possible via headers and i have to create a state model in between.